# How do I find out what is actually set to "${ ... }" in AWS IAM policy?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm trying to limit access to items in Dynamo DB tables based on Cognito User Pool using Lambda IAM role policy.

In the process, I'm struggling to find what is actually set to "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}" in the Lambda IAM policy below.

```
 {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:*:*"
        }
```

I'm assuming it is either Application Client ID or Identity Pool ID like "ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxx-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-123456789012", but is there a way to output what is actually set to "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}" on runtime to confirm?

I am relatively new to AWS.

**Updated - Additional Information**

Just before calling the Lambda via API Gateway, I can see something like "xxxxxxxxnv0ff03e9joqh3om3h" (my App Client ID) using below:

```
const session = await Auth.currentSession();
alert(session.idToken.payload.aud); //something like "xxxxxxxxnv0ff03e9joqh3om3h"
```

However, I get AccessDeniedException in Lambda DynamoDB query with the App Client ID.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ":partitionkey": "xxxxxxxxnv0ff03e9joqh3om3h",
},
```

I can avoid AccessDeniedException error by changing the IAM Policy to:

```
"Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": "123abc"
                }
            },
```

and my Lambda DynamoDB query to:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ":partitionkey": "123abc",
},
```

I've tried Cognito Identity Pool ID too, but no luck.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html seems to be the identity pool.

Comment: There is not really a way to see its value / output - where would you want / expect to see the output in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to see what is in there to debug. The query in Lambda to get DynamoDB items has to match with the IAM policy to avoid permission errors. However, I've been unsuccessful to match using Application Client ID nor Identity Pool ID. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The mapped values for `aud` and `sub` are provider specific and [outlined in the documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/provider-mappings.html)

In the case of Cognito Userpool federation it will be set to the client ID.

Comment: Thanks, that is the most relevant documentation. However, I couldn't make my DynamoDB query working with App Client ID.

Comment: @Taka ah you’re just the latest victim of AWS’s confusing documentation. They fail to distinguish userpool from identity pool. In order to use the string interpolation mechanism in your role you need to use identity pool along with the IAM authorizer on your api gateway.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I'll try to use a custom Lambda Authorizer to create a policy on the fly based on the logged-in user pool if that is possible.

Comment: @Taka oh careful there too. The policy returned by the custom authorizer is only used for API Gateway authorization. What you are looking for is strictly a feature of identity pool.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Andrew, and yes I realized what you meant after trying custom authorizer. I'm now back to IAM auth and again tried many different combinations. However, I still have no idea what is actually set to the aud or sub.

Comment: @Taka The `aud` value will be the client ID of the application in your userpool. The `sub` value will be a pairwise subject id that is unique for each user. This is different from the sub value in the userpool as it is generated uniquely for each application. It's a source of headaches when migrating so it's worthwhile mapping the sub to email (or other unique identifier) mapping in dynamodb in case you need it.